# Searching for fantasy campaign setting with settlements of light and dark separated by permanent clouds

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, campaign-settings, product-identification, wizards-of-the-coast

A long time ago I was listening to a D&D podcast by WoTC in which they briefly described a new campaign setting they were thinking of creating.  I don't know if they ever did and my Google searches and searches of their site have come up empty.  I'd like to create something similar for my campaign and want to borrow from any such setting that might exist.  I'm too lazy to create it on my own if I don't need to.

The setting was a world in which the highlands and mountain tops were separated from the lowlands and valleys by a permanent thick cloud cover.  Those that dwelt high enough were in continual light and travelled between these 'islands' that exist above the clouds via sky ships.  Beneath the clouds it was continual darkness where the hordes of evil stuff and other nasties lived.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?  Has such a campaign setting been created?

Comment: Okay, that's really weird. That's a setting seed I created years ago, circa 2003 or so. Either it's not a very original setting idea and WotC and I both thought of that, or you mistook an ancient blog post of mine for a WotC idea. ^^

Comment: If you've written up the setting, use that as an answer. Worst case is someone else posts the WotC setting as well.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Just the seed, and it was only about twice as many words as the OP's paragraph describing it. I'll see if I can find the link though. I think it was back when LiveJournal was still a thing people used.

Comment: I remember something like this from an episode of a TV show I watched many years ago. It was some sci-fi show where the "heroes" traveled to this strange place like what you are describing. (But I can't remember anything more than that - not even which show it was!) - Try asking in [scifi.se] using the tag [story-identification](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie so, after all, it was yours (with a different nick) the linked blog, or you two came up independently with basically the same idea?

Comment: @Lohoris Probably independent invention. (That old LJ blog of mine does use a different nickname, yes.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found what you were looking for!

[This blog](http://blogofholding.com/?p=5937) led me to [the podcast link](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4pod/20130510).

Excerpt:

> On the latest WOTC D&D podcast, Steve Winter talked about the great
>   campaign-world books that came out of Second Edition D&D. He said
>   that, for every kick-ass setting like Planescape or Al'Quadim, they
>   had a bunch of ideas just as good - they just didn't have time to
>   print them all. Prompted, he described one of the settings that he'd
>   never forgotten:
>
> There's one that always comes to mind: it was proposed by Jeff Grubb,
>   and I forget what the name of it was, but the idea was, it was a world
>   where there were all these mountain ranges, and all of civilization -
>   the good part of civilization - has been driven up to the tops of
>   these mountains, and then there's a tremendously thick cloud layer, so
>   wherever the sun shines is where good exists. Everything beneath the
>   cloud layer has been overrun by evil. There are cloud ships that sail
>   out from these mountain-top cities across the clouds, and the
>   adventurers rappel down to the world where they go raiding the ruined
>   cities that used to be down there, looking for gold, metal, and all
>   the kinds of things that they don't have in these mountaintop cities.
>
> As Steve Winter says, that idea isn't quite as fresh as it was in the
>   late 80s (he's seen elements in anime, and it reminds me of Final
>   Fantasy) but I think it's still an evocative and inspiring world. I'm
>   ready to play it! But, since all we have is a podcast sound bite and
>   not a campaign book, I'm left with a lot of questions: exactly what
>   kind of evil lurks in the cloudy lowlands? What does the wilderness
>   look like?

That blog leads to many interesting ideas, and there are some very wonderful comments there. Unfortunately - it seems that it was never more than an idea, so there is not much campaign setting for you to use in yours. But *why don't you be the one to write it?*

Incidentally, while searching for your lost podcast, I found some related and interesting things for you to explore:

- An RPG Manual called [Monsters Magic and Sky ships](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/87847/monsters-magic-and-sky-ships)
- A D&D Supplement called [Champions of Mystara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champions_of_Mystara)
- A post about an adventure called [Cloud Trek](http://forum.rpg.net/archive/index.php/t-574153.html)
- The start of a campaign setting based on the blog post called [Eleven Pillars](http://www.rpgmusings.com/2013/06/eleven-pillars-post/)

---

Update: This story idea has been sitting in my mind since I answered this question almost 5 months ago. I could not resist the urge to use it for one of my games on the new Storium website. [Here is the link](https://storium.com/game/the-lightside-chronicles), so that anyone looking for information about this can easily connect.

Comment: +1 Nailed it!  Thanks for the extra links, some I knew of, some I didn't. I particularly liked the Eleven Pillars postings.

Comment: @user1166636 You are very welcome, I enjoyed the research, and I would love if you could share your campaign setting/details with me (or the rest of the community) somehow. You can usually meet us in the [RPG general chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat). Cheers.